# Como capturar campo do formulario com o .htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou fazendo no meu site url amigáveis, porém, estou com dificuldades para capturar o campo de busca do formulário com o .htaccess. Todas as minhas tentativas dão erro 404.

**Formulário:**

```
<form action="busca" method="post">
<input type="text" name="busca" required="required" class="buscar-frm">
</form>
```

htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^busca/([0-9]+)/?$ /imv.php?busca=$1 [NC]
```

Foi tentado utilizar tanto o `method` post quanto o get. No campo busca, é apenas para buscar por código do imóvel.

Quando dou enter no campo de busca, vai para página com erro 404, e não para a imv.php

Comment: Veja nos logs do Apache o que você está recebendo. Ao usar o método GET para o envio do formulário, o valor aparecerá na URL sendo algo como "busca?busca={valor}" (o campo ficará listado, daí você deve considerá-lo ao fazer a busca).

Comment: @GiovanniNunes Continua dando erro 404, não vai para a pagina imv.php tanto utilizando post ou get

Comment: Por favor se eu te ajudei, marque como melhor resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A confusão ta no .htaccess, vc ta fazendo uma requisição POST e esperando um GET. Fiz esse código e aqui ta funcionando, teste ai.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^busca/([0-9]+)/?$ /teste/imv.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

imv.php

```
<h1>Encontrado:</h1> <?php echo $_POST['busca'] ?>
```

index.php:

```
<form action="busca/1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="busca" required="required" class="buscar-frm">
    <button type="submit"> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução. Perfeita!